# Phonegap & Cordova - How to remove default splash screen?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, splash-screen

When I used to start up my app, it would show the common splash screen: [https://www.google.com/search?biw=1366&bih=667&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=cordova+android+splash+screen&oq=cordova+android+splash+screen&gs_l=img.3...3442.4414.0.4584.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.0.0.HlLmVH4tGUs#imgrc=HJeAimnld9GDKM%3A](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1366&bih=667&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=cordova%20android%20splash%20screen&oq=cordova%20android%20splash%20screen&gs_l=img.3...3442.4414.0.4584.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.0.0.HlLmVH4tGUs#imgrc=HJeAimnld9GDKM%3A)

Now it seems it cuts off about 1/10th of the top of the image and covers the screen with it for the initial few seconds, THEN my app starts normally, like so:

[image: Splash Screen]

I have been ignoring it until I finished the app, now I am nearly done publishing and wish to fix this issue.

I was wondering if there is a way to take out the splash screen entirely. I tried removing the pictures from res/xml and adding

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="none"/>
```

but doesn't work.

This is for an android app.

I am going to make it for iOS soon after I finish and publish for android, so if they are different methods for different platforms, please include.

Answer (score 0):

The Cordova documentation about icons and splash screens is:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/images.html

but if you need more control over splash screens (via JS) you can add this plugin:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen